# Authentication on verifying email with keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm working on email verification in keycloak.
When user create account on register, an email is sent to verify his email. But when he clicks on the link, it's directly redirect to "my account page".
This is pretty strange for me.
I saw that keycloak recognize the client with the cookie AUTH_SESSION_ID because if client click on link from an other browser he had to click on "click here" before access to his "my account page".

Is it possible to break the first behavior?

Thanks